# How we can copy custom elements from parent window inside iframe window?

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I have an application where I have loaded a few custom elements (Via js file ) and added iframe and loaded a page inside the iframe.

Can we copy all custom elements inside the frame window without adding custom elements js file reference?

Answer (score 0):

- The `customElementsRegistry` is a window Global object
- An IFrame is **another** window

So they **do not *share*** Registry/Custom Elements

There is an ongoing discussion on **Scoped Registries**
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/716

But that is more about **multiple registries** within **one window/document**

Its is unlikely your IFrame scenario will be tackled;

So just add your `elements.js` to the HTML file loaded in the IFrame

Comment: I wanted to get rid of element.js file since its already available in parent window.                                                           let logo = window.parent.customElements.get('my-logo')                                                            assiging this to iframe window :  window.customElements.define('my-logo', logo); is this is a right way ?

Comment: You are overcomplicating and creating dependencies you would have to maintain in the future... The browser has already downloaded ``element.js`` so reusing it in an IFrame can hardly have implications. Think of your components like Images.. you are not going to jump through hoops and read you [Company Logo] from different locations. That is what you want to do now.. instead of defining a Component from its original source, you now want the parent window to be the source. KISS - Keep It Simple S....

Comment: Currently I am injecting js file to each pages but my concern is since it is already available in parent winow then child window can create necessary elements on runtime so that all pages no need to load entire elements.js which is bigger in size and i can save some hookup time.

Comment: No, you are only requesting your "BaseClass" from a different source.. and I wouldn't be surprised that is actually slower than requesting the file again.. because that file is cached, already processed by the **Browser** engine...just like it handles the same Image (or any file) URI .. replicating that behaviour by calling the **JavaScript** engine will always be slower. Again.. treat your ``element.js`` as your [Company Logo] image file.. you are using the same URI also (I hope).. you are not calling the parent window (where the logo is used) and pulling IMG binary data into your IFrames.